# Django Automatically Logging Out User , when he goes to Registration Page

Tags: django, django-urls, django-authentication, django-registration, django-login

Thanks In Advance.

I am facing an Issue in one of my Django Website. Here an authenticated user can access the Registration Page. But the client raised it as an issue. So I have tried to rectify that Issue and ended up with the following Solution.

Is it a good solution? Or how can I make it good?

The Process should be like this, when a loginned user try to access the Registration Page, he should be automatically Logged Out from the Site and then redirected to the Registration Page.

My code is

```
def user_signup(request, template_name='profiles/profile_register_form.html'):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return custom_logout(request, next_page = "/accounts/register/")


def custom_logout(request, next_page='/'):
try:
    language = request.session['django_language']
except:
    language = False
response = logout(request, next_page=next_page)
if language:
    request.session['django_language'] = language
return response
```

Comment: Looks find for me, is there anything specific you do not like?

Comment: something opposite to the decorator @login_required ?

Comment: so what is the question then, you seem to hav working code, now you just need to put it into a decorator function. Thake a look at the source of @login_required, plug in your code, done.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question then

why `custom_logout`

you can call directly django logout like

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')  # whatever you register page
```

Comment: **custom_logout** is for setting some language cookie

Comment: ok then you can do one thing once you store your cookie and all then after you can call HttpResponseRedirect() to redirect your page on register.html

Comment: thats not very usefull for me. What I meant is something opposite for @login_required

Answer (score 0):

Your method was correct. It will save the current language session and will do the exact process you need